# How to check if column having date of birth format has yyyymmdd in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to check if column having date of birth format has yyyymmdd in sql server?

Comment: Are you asking how to verify a *character field* is a valid yyyymmdd?  Please add what version of MSSQL you are using.

Comment: What have you tried to implement so far?

Comment: Please be more specific.  Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Date format isn't really like that, it's a special format that is just date, display format is just for the display. If you want it to appear in a certain way in your query, apply a format in the select.

Comment: You don't check to see if it is in the "right" format. You instead make your column datatype date or datetime. Don't use the incorrect datatypes and these types of issues resolve themselves. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Date Fields don't have any format, they are stored as binary (a numeric value). It's your client application that formats that value when presenting it, depending of the settings you have defined on that client application.

Comment: Is your column varchar or datetime?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify with the ISDATE Function, but I don't know which SQL edition do you have

Example

```
select ISDATE ( 1 )  
------------------
0
select ISDATE ( 11111111 )  
------------------
0
select ISDATE ( 20170501)  
------------------
1
```

Comment: But it also says if SELECT IsDate('2017-05-01') also as 1. I think OP is looking to find whether it is in YYYYMMDD format alone...

Comment: Yes, the funcion Identifies valid dates like this select ISDATE ( '01/05/2015') .

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select (case when try_convert(date, dob) is not null and
                  try_convert(int, dob) is not null
             then 1 else 0
        end)
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that yyyymmdd is the only format that will generally pass both conditions.  Note:  There is no way to know if 20170601 is really June 1st or Jan 6th, so this cannot actually validate the contents of the field.

But why do you care what the format is, so long as you can convert it to a date?  You should then change the column to a date type and henceforth know that the "format" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a Char type (yuck) then Like '[12][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]' (off the top of my head)

If it's a DateTime then who cares, it's a date.